# ListView.setClickable() doesn't work. (Nativescript-Vue)

Tags: javascript, listview, nativescript, nativescript-vue, nativescript-telerik-ui

I'm writting Nativescript-Vue app.

I have a component with two child components in it. 
So when I'm tapping a button placed in the second one, I need to disable scrolling of ListView placed in the first one.

So I took my ListView element via "ref=" and put it in store (Vuex)

```
<ListView ref="listViewEl" ></ListView>
...
mounted() {
    store.commit('putElInStore', this.$refs.listViewEl)
}

...

putElInStore(state, element) {
    state.listViewEl = element
}
```

I need to make ListView scrolling disabled when I'm tapping a button in the second child component. So I do it using store.commit:

```
<Button @tap="disableListViewScrolling"></Button>
...
disableListViewScrolling() {
    store.commit('disableScrolling')
}

...

disableScrolling(state) {
    state.listViewEl.nativeView.android.setClickable(false)
}
```

So I don't get any errors in this case, but there is no any reaction at all. It just doesn't work.

I also tried using setEnabled(false) instead of. It works, but incorrectly.

What do I miss? Where is my mistake?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There shouldn't be any need to store the element in Vuex. Without the full code I'll give a you a general layout of how this could be performed.

```
<Parent>
    <childOne ref="listViewChild"></childOne>
    <childTwo @disableButtonTapped="$refs.listViewChild.disableClick()"></childTwo>
</Parent>
```

```
<childOne> 
   <ListView ref="list"></ListView>
</childOne>

<script>
export defaults {
  methods: {
    disableClick () {
      this.$refs.list.nativeView.android.setClickable(false)
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

```
<childTwo> 
   <Button @tap="$emit('disableButtonTapped')"></Button>
</childTwo>
```

Obviously this code isn't exact.

Comment: In conjunction to this you could also use `:isUserInteractionDisabled="someProp"` instead if you need to disable interaction entirely. then you manage the state of interaction from the prop instead of toggling it via the ref.